# An unexpected errors occured with Yarn 1.13.0 on Xubuntu 16

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, yarnpkg

I managed to get the latest Yarn v1.13.0 installed on Xubuntu 16 with their curl installation instruction.

Now I'm getting this errors trying to install a project's dependencies.

> An expected error occurred:
>   "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/event-stream/-/event-stream-3.3.6.tgz:
>   Request failed \"404 Not Found\

Same 'Not Found' message is displayed by the error url.

Seems to be caused by the security issue https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream/issues/116?utm_content=educational&utm_campaign=2018-11-28&utm_source=email-sendgrid&utm_term=13952972&utm_medium=833442

How do I fix it? How do I find the project deps that use the corrupted version of event-stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seemingly was caused by an older version of Nodemon prolly affected by the security issue above. Updating it to the latest version in package.json seemed to have helped.